# How do you counter Sammohanastra?

Tags: weapon

Arjuna used Sammohanastra in Virat army that put the Kuru army to sleep. Sammohanastra is a weapon that puts an enemy to sleep.

If somebody hurled agneyastra or fire weapon, then you counter attack with varunastra or water weapon.

How do you counter Sammohanastra?

Comment: By wearing mask as it's chemical weapon

Comment: Sammohanastra was used by Shri Ram against Ravan and Khar as well. It's counter to maya by rakshashas but don't think they had a counter for this. Both khar n ravan sena lost severely to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118436.html This is description of 5th and 6th day of war of mahabharata .Note pramohana is same as sanmohana astra. So, here it is mentioned that Dronacharya countered the Sammohana Astra using an Astra called Prajna.

> Seeing Dhritarastra's sons coming toward his chariot, the Panchala prince summoned his celestial weapon called pramohana and released it above the Kaurava army. That divine weapon deprived the soldiers of their senses, and they fell to the ground helpless. **Drona, seeing the situation, rushed to the aid of the sons of Dhritarastra and released a weapon called prajna, that countered the pramohana weapon**. When their senses again returned, the warriors challenged Bhima and Dhristadyumna, covering them with arrows